# What is the  'moreq' Filter Type an Alias for?

Tags: php, sql, orm, magento

I'm looking in to Magento's filtering options (Ecommerce System and PHP Framekwork with an expansive ORM system). Specifically the `addFieldToFilter` method.  In this method, you specify a SQLish filter by passing in a single element array, with the key indicating the type of filter.  For example,

```
array('eq'=>'bar') //eq means equal
array('neq'=>'bar') //neq means not equal
```

would each give you a where clause that looks like

```
where field = 'bar'; 
where field != 'bar';
```

So, deep in the bowels of the source, I found a comparison type named

```
'moreq'
```

that maps to a >= comparison operator

```
array('moreq'=>'27')
where field >= 27
```

The weird thing is, there's already a 'gteq' comparision type

```
array('gteq'=>'27')
where field >= 27
```

So, my question is, what does moreq stand for?  Is is some special SQL concept that's supported in other databases that the Magento guys wants to map to MySQL, or is it just "more required" and an example what happens when you're doing  rapid agile and trying to maintain backwards compatibility.

Comment: You sometimes use `noreq` and sometimes `moreq`, is this intentional or a typo?

Comment: Nope, not intentional, just a freelancers scattered brain.  Should be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I took some notes for myself on the comparison operators, coming straight from the db collection abstraction. As you can see, moreq is for "greater than or equal to". You are correct that it is a duplicate for gteq, but I've not seen anything in the code that suggests a previous use:

```
from            from
to              to
=               eq
!=              neq
like            like
not like        nlike
in              in
not in          nin
is              is
is not null     notnull
is null         null
>=              moreq
>               gt
<               lt
>=              gteq
<=              lteq
find_in_set()   finset
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe